# FullCalendar: events not rendering initially from function call (AJAX)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, fullcalendar

I've configured my FullCalendar to pull its events from an AJAX request, but they don't render on the calendar when the page is first loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    sh1client = new Array();
    sh2client = new Array();

    $('#sh1_cal').fullCalendar({

         height: 1000,
         minTime:'9:00am',
         maxTime:'5:00pm',
         editable: false,

         events: function(start, end, callback) {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/getEvents',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(reply) {

                    console.log(reply.first);
                    callback(reply.first);

                }
            });
        }
    });


    $("#sh1_cal").fullCalendar('addEventSource', sh1client);   // these are the clientside arrays

});
```

And on the server,

```
app.get('/getEvents', function(req, res){

    console.log('Server: passing events...');

    var arrays = {first: sh1, second: sh2}
    var pack = JSON.stringify(arrays)

    res.writeHead(200, {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    res.end(pack);

});
```

Is there any reason these events wouldn't initially load? Everything seems to be being passed through alright, but it's like the callback isn't working or something.

*EDIT:* Here is another approach I tried

```
events: { 

            url: 'http://localhost:8080/getEvents',
            type: 'GET',

            error: function() {
                alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
            },

            success: function(reply) {
                console.log(reply);
                //callback(reply.first);
            },

            color: 'yellow',   // a non-ajax option
            textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option

         }
```

*EDIT*: JavaScript console shows this as being POSTed to the page as soon as it loads (this is the first object in an array:

```
[Object]
allDay: "false"
end: "1392129000"
id: "phil@google.com"
room: "Sh1"
start: "1392127200"
title: "Phil - Google"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
```

Comment: I'm glad you found solution what did it end up being?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using your own ajax call, have you tried using fullcalendars?

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/

Fullcalendar defaults the dataType as JSON and caching to false.

Combined some of your code with code from doc:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    events: {
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/getEvents',
        type: 'GET',
        error: function() {
            alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
        },
        success: function(reply) {
            console.log(reply.first);
            callback(reply.first);
        },
        color: 'yellow',   // a non-ajax option
        textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option
    }

});
```

You can try just getting your JSON string cutting and pasting in and see if you can render without ajax call

```
     events: [
     {
            end: 1392129000,
            id: "phil@google.com",
            room: "Sh1",
            start: 1392127200,
            title: "Phil - Google"
      }]
```

You can also process the response:

```
$('#myCalendar').fullCalendar({
...
   eventSources : [{
      url: 'myUrl',
      type: 'GET',
   },
   success: function(replyObject) {
      var results = [];
      var reply= replyObject.Results[0];
      for(var index in reply) {
         results.push(reply[index]);
      }
      return results;
    }
    }]
...
```

Comment: I tried this as well, but it didn't work. I updated the question with the code from this approach

Comment: Can you provide an example of the json your url returns?

Comment: I see one issue with your allDay value that is "false" and not just false.

Comment: I've removed that field entirely now, issue persists

Comment: I may have located the problem -- when I POST the object, it returns to the client with all the values converted to strings (even the date objects) which I think is not allowing it to render. Is there a way to prevent the POST operation from doing this?

Comment: Try running the string through JSON.parse(json_text) in your console, then grab from there.

Comment: The thing is, it's not the entire object that is a string -- it's still an object, but its values are strings. So I can't parse the entire object.

Comment: And using this method of loading the events into the calendar doesn't give me a chance to parse them before they are rendered.

Comment: Also your unix timestamps need to be a number and not a string.